# How to store multiple lines separated by enter value in a single variable in python? Example is in the description

Tags: python, list, variables

```
555
554
33
2444
4555
2455
24555
2555
2335
5555
23455
2455
2344
```

I want to store all these values in the single variable num, how can I do that?

Comment: that is in a text file ? have looked for "read a file in python" ?

Comment: The answer is in your question tags: use a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with a multiple line string you can use `split` given `"\n"` as the splitor:

```
myString = """
555
554
33
2444
4555
2455
24555
2555
2335
5555
23455
2455
2344
"""
myString.strip().split("\n")
```

##### Output

```
['555',
 '554',
 '33',
 '2444',
 '4555',
 '2455',
 '24555',
 '2555',
 '2335',
 '5555',
 '23455',
 '2455',
 '2344']
```

Note that if you are working with file, you can still use the same approach, but you need to read the file first.

Comment: Would myString.split() achieve the same thing? i.e., no strip() and no parameter passed to split()

Comment: @LancelotduLac Thanks for your comment. Yes! Of course, that does the job. But, in my opinion, to make it more clear for the OP, it is kinda necessary to point to what separator we are using. But, you are absolutely right. And about the `strip` function, it could be useful in the case of dealing with multiple line strings, because we are not sure whether or not there are unwanted spaces/brake lines at the end and beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `\n` in python to create a new line. For example, this prints out what your example to the console: `print("555\n554\n33\n2444\n4555\n2455\n24555\n2555\n2335\n5555\n23455\n2455\n234")`

If you wanted to write something to a file, you can do something similar to:

```
numbers = [number, number, more_numbers]  # Create a list containing numbers
file = open("file.txt", "w")  # Opens file.txt in write mode 
for number in numbers:  # Loop through the numbers in list
    file.write(number\n)  # Writes numbers with line breaks after each one in the list
```

If you simply wanted to print out the numbers in the list, replace the `file.write(number\n)` with `print(number\n)`. And remove the `file = open` line. You can always use `\n` to create a new line.

Answer (score 0):

```
num=list(555,
554,
33,
2444,
4555,
2455,
24555,
2555,
2335,
5555,
2345,
2455,
2344)
```